# GNU make: How to wait "cp" command to finish

Tags: bash, ubuntu, makefile, gnu-make

my makefile:

```
make:
# Mount Loader.bin
    sudo mount -t vfat -o loop Boot.img mnt
    sudo cp Loader.bin mnt
    sudo umount mnt
```

However, the results present an error with "target busy"

```
$ make make
sudo mount -t vfat -o loop Boot.img mnt
[sudo] password for shore: 
sudo cp Loader.bin mnt
sudo umount mnt
umount: /home/shore/MineOS/mnt: target is busy.
makefile:7: recipe for target 'make' failed
make: *** [make] Error 32
```

It randomly occurs and I guess the main idea is that unmouont are executed while copy is in process.

Thus I would like to ask if there is a way that it will wait the previous command finish then execute the next command

By the way, my platform is Ubuntu 18.4

Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make only ever runs one line in a recipe at a time and it always waits for the previous line to complete before running the next one.  It has to wait, because if the current line fails the recipe must fail without starting the next line.

What is probably happening is that the `cp` is exiting, but the data has not been fully flushed to the mounted filesystem: the kernel is still writing out the buffered data.  So even though the copy command has finished, the partition is still busy.

Perhaps you can force it to sync using something like (here I'm assuming you're using GNU/Linux or something compatible):

```
make:
# Mount Loader.bin
        sudo mount -t vfat -o loop Boot.img mnt
        sudo cp Loader.bin mnt
        sudo sync -f mnt/Loader.bin
        sudo umount mnt
```

I don't know if that will be sufficient to force it or not.

BTW, it's usually a good idea to use `sudo -n` when you're using `sudo` in a makefile or any other non-interactive environment.

Comment: Hi I think you are right, but the code does not work, same problem occurs. My current way is to sleep 0.5, would you have any better method. Thank you~

Comment: How about retrying from some time just in case it fails?  `for ((i=0; i<10; i++)); do umount mnt && break; sleep 0.2; done`.

Comment: You could also use option `-l` to unmount lazily.  This will remove the FS from the directory hierarchy quickly and unmount it as soon as the reason for the unmount failing is gone.

Comment: @Shore The retrying is not exactly the same as a mere sleep but of course it shares some properties with this solution.

Comment: @Alfe Yep, I may try it...... I wonder if cp has some options that to exit after the copy process.....

Comment: @Alfe using "cp -v" option will display the process of copying, which also provide the utility of exit after copy finished~~ Thank you both!!

Comment: I think the `cp` isn't to blame here.  It is rather a (mis)feature of the file system you are using that some writing access _appears_ to be finished _before_ the hardware can be safely ejected because normally ejects don't happen.  The best way I can think of is to wait for the eject (unmount) to finish, and polling is the only safe way I can think of.  The `-l` option is a nice alternative but also doesn't allow for instant removal of the hardware.

Comment: If `cp -v` would help in this case that would be really weird.  Test thoroughly if this appears to be the case because I cannot really believe it and rather believe in a chance effect you are seeing at some trials.

Comment: @Alfe hmmmmm, till now cp -v works fine. Actually what I'm doing is to mount a disk image, copy some files in and unmount it. The image are files created by bochs. To make it easier I wrote the makefile to mount, copy and umnount. I tested cp - v and till now it works fine. However, the appearance of the error are random. What I would do is to copy a bigger file and see if it works, also I'll try cp -l to see if it makes any different. Thank you lol~

Comment: @Alfe well you are right, the problem shows again. I guess the printing process made extra time for copy to be finished. Currently the best way for me is just to sleep for 0.5s.........

Comment: Why not just repeating to try to unmount until it succeeded?